# NumPy construct a new matrix without rowi,columnj keeping row,column indices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pandas

I have a matrix with size `m * n` (m rows and n columns). There is a cell at the position `(i,j)` and I want to construct a new matrix with size `(m-1)*(n-1)` where the new matrix doesn't include the row and column the cell reside with the original indices kept.

For example, my input matrix is like this:

```
    1    2    3    4
1   a11  a12  a13- a14
2   a21- a22- a23* a24-
3   a31  a32  a33- a34
4   a41  a42  a43- a44
```

(* next to `a23` means it is the given element, the elements with dash next to it are going to be removed in the output)

Given `(i,j)` say (2,3) for example, I want my output to be:

```
    1    2    4
1   a11  a12  a14
3   a31  a32  a34
4   a41  a42  a44
```

This is what I have tried in `NumPy`:

```
def myfunction(mymatrix=bipartite, row_idx=0, column_idx=0):
    row_indices = range(mymatrix.shape[0])
    row_indices.remove(row_idx)
    column_indices = range(mymatrix.shape[1])
    column_indices.remove(column_idx)
    result = mymatrix[np.ix_(row_indices, column_indices)]
    return result

print bipartite

print myfunction(bipartite, 2, 3)

[[1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1]]
[[1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1]]
```

However, in the new matrix, I lost the original column and row indices.

Can anyone help me with that?

Or I am even not in the ballpark since matrix in `Numpy` won't preserve the row and columns names anyway which I have to use `DataFrame` in `Pandas` to simulate a matrix in that case?

Comment: `numpy` never assigns row and column names.  It just counts rows and columns.  Names, if any, are in separate arrays or lists - either ones that `pandas` creates, or ones you create and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve any index information, it's probably simplest in Pandas. You can do it by dropping the relevant rows / columns after you've read in the array.

For example:

```
>>> M = np.random.rand((4, 4))
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(M)
>>> df
          0         1         2         3
0  0.826425  0.888413  0.320257  0.079322
1  0.637170  0.144950  0.370768  0.967574
2  0.674793  0.995937  0.683142  0.403560
3  0.388024  0.619652  0.948890  0.088462
```

Dropping row `1` and column `2`:

```
>>> df.drop(1, axis=0).drop(2, axis=1)
          0         1         3
0  0.826425  0.888413  0.079322
2  0.674793  0.995937  0.403560
3  0.388024  0.619652  0.088462
```

Comment: Ah, thanks... I re-read your question and saw that the mask was in effect doing the same as your code (and so might not have been what you were after). I can add it back in if you think it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
def minor(arr, i, j):
    # ith column, jth row removed
    return arr[np.array(range(i)+range(i+1, arr.shape[0]))[:,np.newaxis],
               np.array(range(j)+range(j+1,arr.shape[1]))]

arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
print(arr)
# [[ 0  1  2  3]
#  [ 4  5  6  7]
#  [ 8  9 10 11]
#  [12 13 14 15]]

print(minor(arr, 2, 3))
```

yields

```
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [12 13 14]]
```